# alert message displays multiple time by Jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my alert message is being displayed thrice or even 4 times cant able to identify the problem but i know i need to give unbind but do no where to place.any help would be appreciated.thank you

```js
jQuery('#compleave,#prevleave,#sickleave,#vacation').on('click', function(event) {     
    
 
 jQuery('#show2').show();
     $("#but").remove();
     if (this.id == 'prevleave') {

      document.getElementById("ldays").value = but1_val2;
         document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Privilege Leave";
     }
     else if (this.id == 'compleave') {
      document.getElementById("ldays").value = but1_val1;
         document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Dubai Casual Leave"; 
     }
     else if (this.id == 'sickleave') {
      document.getElementById("ldays").value = but_val3;
         document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Sickness";
     }
     else if (this.id == 'vacation') {
      document.getElementById("ldays").value = but_val4;
         document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Vacation";
     }
    

     $("#apply").click(funcapply);
});
function funcapply()
{
  alert("HELLO CHECK THIS");
}
```

```html
<div id="but">
<input type="button" id="prevleave" class="appButton1" value="Privilege Leave"> <br> <br>
<input type="button" id="compleave" class="appButton1" value="Dubai Casual Leave"> <br> <br>
<input type="button" id="sickleave" class="appButton1" value="Sickness"> <br> <br>
<input type="button" id="vacation" class="appButton1" value="Vacation"> <br> <br>
</div>

<div id="show2" class="container1" style="display:none;">
 
<label>LEAVE DAYS: </label> <input type="text" id="ldays"><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="applleave" value="APPLY LEAVE" id="apply" onclick="funcapply();">
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you are assigning click event inside event handler of four elements. Move it out.

Comment: can't see the alerts when I run your code snippet.

Comment: $("#apply").click(funcapply); i wrote outside the jquery scope same problem

Comment: isuue cannot be duplictated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the funcapply function two times.
Just replace the input html as

```
<input type="submit" class="applleave" value="APPLY LEAVE" id="apply"/>
```

means you need to remove the onclick event from it, as it is already used

```
$("#apply").click(funcapply);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `$("#apply").click(funcapply);`  from onClick event to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#apply").click(funcapply);
})
```

This will receive click event only after markup is ready to receive event. i.e. click event in your case.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bny29ew/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   $("#apply").click(funcapply); // when click on apply leaves

   jQuery('#compleave,#prevleave,#sickleave,#vacation').click(function(event) {
     jQuery('#show2').show();
     $("#but").remove();
     if (this.id == 'prevleave') {

       document.getElementById("ldays").value = but1_val2;
       document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Privilege Leave";
     } else if (this.id == 'compleave') {
       document.getElementById("ldays").value = but1_val1;
       document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Dubai Casual Leave";
     } else if (this.id == 'sickleave') {
       document.getElementById("ldays").value = but_val3;
       document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Sickness";
     } else if (this.id == 'vacation') {
       document.getElementById("ldays").value = but_val4;
       document.getElementById("ltype").value = "Vacation";
     }


   });

   function funcapply() {
     alert("HELLO CHECK THIS");
   }
```

[Run Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1bny29ew/3/)